# How to set animation unset when it is hovered

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-animation-direction

I want to add animated footer to my project. It has animation which goes from right to left and then disapears, and it is in the loop. I want it to stop when it is hovered but since there are 2 animation, I want both of them stop when .Footer class is hovered. So html:

```
<footer class="Footer">
  <ul class="Footer-items">
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/JeremBoo" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-twitter"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--<li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-google-plus"></span>
      </a>
    </li>-->
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Jeremboo" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-github"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/Jeremboo/" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-codepen"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://fr.linkedin.com/in/j%C3%A9r%C3%A9mie-boulay-9b005a51" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-linkedin"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="mailto:jeremi.boulay@gmail.com" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-envelope"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

And this is the css:

/* INIT */

```
$logoSize : 50px;
$wrapperWidth : $logoSize*6;
$animationDuration : 3000ms;

html, body, ul {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
html, body{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow : hidden;
  font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration : none;
}

.f {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  color : #070707;
}

.f a {
  color : #FFC6C6;
}

/* FOOTER */

.Footer {
  position : absolute;
  top : 50%;
  right : 5%;
  transform:translateY( -50% );
}

.Footer::before {
  content : '';
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 25%;
  right : 0;
  width : $wrapperWidth;
  height : 25%;
  background-color : #FFC6C6;
  animation : translate1 $animationDuration infinite;
}

.Footer-items {
  width : $wrapperWidth;
  float : right;
}
.Footer-item {
  display : inline-block;
  width : $logoSize;
  height : $logoSize;
  text-align: center;
}
.Footer-link {
  position : relative;
  display: block;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  opacity : 0;
  animation : translate2 $animationDuration infinite;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(2) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : ($animationDuration/50);
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(3) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : ($animationDuration/50)*2;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(4) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : ($animationDuration/50)*3;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(5) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : ($animationDuration/50)*4;
}

.Footer-icon {
  color : #070707;
  position: absolute;
  left : 50%;
  top : 50%;
  font-size : 1.6em;
  transform : translate( -50%, -50% );
  transition : 0.3s;
}

.fa-codepen, .fa-linkedin, .fa-envelope { 
  font-size : 1.4em;
}
.fa-linkedin { 
  font-size : 1.5em;
}
.fa-envelope { 
  font-size : 1.3em;
}

.Footer-link:hover {  
  .Footer-icon {
    top : 30%;
  }
  /*.fa-twitter { 
    color : #3498db;
  }
  .fa-google-plus { 
    color : #E34429;
  }
  .fa-github { 
    color : #9C7A5B;
  }
   .fa-linkedin { 
    color : #34495e;
  }
   .fa-codepen { 
    color : #161616;
  }*/
}


@keyframes translate1{
  0% { opacity : 0; margin-right : -7%; }
  20% { opacity : 1; margin-right : 0; }
  65% { opacity : 1; margin-right : 0; }
  85% { opacity : 0; margin-right : 10%; }
  100% { opacity : 0; margin-right : 10%; }
}
@keyframes translate2{
  2% { opacity : 0; margin-left : 175%; }
  21% { opacity : 1; margin-left : 0%; }
  64% { opacity : 1; margin-left : 0%; }
  80% { opacity : 0; margin-left : -250%; }
  100% { opacity : 0; margin-left : -250%; }
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve when it is hovered to .Footer, I want to set animation to unset but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: hi, sorry for my bad English. I think You should put animate to the footer-item class and put hover on the footer element

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with CSS too. add this CSS at the end to style tag

```
.Footer:hover {
    --animationDuration : null;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --logoSize : 50px;
  --wrapperWidth : 300px;
  --animationDuration : 3000ms;
}

html, body, ul {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
html, body{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow : hidden;
  font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration : none;
}

.f {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  color : #070707;
}

.f a {
  color : #FFC6C6;
}

/* FOOTER */

.Footer {
  position : absolute;
  top : 50%;
  right : 5%;
  transform:translateY( -50% );
}

.Footer::before {
  content : '';
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 25%;
  right : 0;
  width : var(--wrapperWidth);
  height : 25%;
  background-color : #FFC6C6;
  animation : translate1 var(--animationDuration) infinite;
}

.Footer-items {
  width : var(--wrapperWidth);
  float : right;
}
.Footer-item {
  display : inline-block;
  width : var(--logoSize);
  height : var(--logoSize);
  text-align: center;
}
.Footer-link {
  position : relative;
  display: block;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  opacity : 0;
  animation : translate2 var(--animationDuration) infinite;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(2) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : (var(--animationDuration)/50);
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(3) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : (var(--animationDuration)/50)*2;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(4) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : (var(--animationDuration)/50)*3;
}
.Footer-item:nth-child(5) .Footer-link {
  animation-delay : (var(--animationDuration)/50)*4;
}

.Footer-icon {
  color : #070707;
  position: absolute;
  left : 50%;
  top : 50%;
  font-size : 1.6em;
  transform : translate( -50%, -50% );
  transition : 0.3s;
}

.fa-codepen, .fa-linkedin, .fa-envelope { 
  font-size : 1.4em;
}
.fa-linkedin { 
  font-size : 1.5em;
}
.fa-envelope { 
  font-size : 1.3em;
}

.Footer-link:hover {  
  .Footer-icon {
    top : 30%;
  }
  /*.fa-twitter { 
    color : #3498db;
  }
  .fa-google-plus { 
    color : #E34429;
  }
  .fa-github { 
    color : #9C7A5B;
  }
   .fa-linkedin { 
    color : #34495e;
  }
   .fa-codepen { 
    color : #161616;
  }*/
}


@keyframes translate1{
  0% { opacity : 0; margin-right : -7%; }
  20% { opacity : 1; margin-right : 0; }
  65% { opacity : 1; margin-right : 0; }
  85% { opacity : 0; margin-right : 10%; }
  100% { opacity : 0; margin-right : 10%; }
}
@keyframes translate2{
  2% { opacity : 0; margin-left : 175%; }
  21% { opacity : 1; margin-left : 0%; }
  64% { opacity : 1; margin-left : 0%; }
  80% { opacity : 0; margin-left : -250%; }
  100% { opacity : 0; margin-left : -250%; }
}
.Footer:hover {
    --animationDuration : null;
}
```

```html
<footer class="Footer">
  <ul class="Footer-items">
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/JeremBoo" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-twitter"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--<li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-google-plus"></span>
      </a>
    </li>-->
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Jeremboo" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-github"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/Jeremboo/" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-codepen"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="https://fr.linkedin.com/in/j%C3%A9r%C3%A9mie-boulay-9b005a51" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-linkedin"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="Footer-item"><a target="_blank" href="mailto:jeremi.boulay@gmail.com" class="Footer-link">
      <span class="Footer-icon fa fa-envelope"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can't I do it only with css?

Comment: @eysan answer updated to your need check again

Comment: Thanks for your effort but thats not the correct answer